# Colored custom bytefield

Tags: macros, bytefield

I've made a `bytefield` packet (see picture), and I want to color the field with the field `256-bit RSA Signature` :

[image]

Here is the code I used (from [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270341/28926)) :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table, usenames,dvips, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}
    \begin{bytefield}{32}
        \bitheader{0,2,4,16, 31} \\
        \bitbox{2}{12} & \bitbox{2}{\textcolor{WildStrawberry}{65}} & \bitbox[lrt]{28}{}\\
        \wordbox[lr]{1}{\textcolor{WildStrawberry}{65}-bit EC Public Key}\\
        \bitbox[lrb]{5}{} & \bitbox[lrt]{27}{}\\
        \wordbox[lr]{3}{256-bit RSA Signature} \\
        \bitbox[lrb]{5}{} & \bitbox[lt]{27}{}\\
    \end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

I have seen the (not so common) trick to color a field in the `bytefield` package. They create a command to add a colored boxe, like this :

```
\newcommand{\colorbitbox}[3]{%
 \rlap{\bitbox{#2}{\color{#1}\rule{\width}{\height}}}%
 \bitbox{#2}{#3}
}%
```

It works well for *classical* fields, but the `\colorbitbox` created doesn't allow `\bytefiled` with options like `[lrb]`.

**How can I do this for a field splitted on multiple lines ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to modify `\colorbitbox` to accept the optional parameter and declare an equivalent `\colorwordbox`.

The problem is that the result is not nice, you can see on top figure below. 
Width `word` fields original definition is not possible to just draw some part of its borders as it's needed in this example.

So my best solution (second bytefield code)  is that you manually divide each `wordbox` in as many as needed `bitbox`. The result is the second figure.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\colorbitbox}[4][]{%
\rlap{\bitbox[#1]{#3}{\color{#2}\rule{\width}{\height}}}%
\bitbox[#1]{#3}{#4}}

\newcommand{\colorwordbox}[4][]{%
\rlap{\wordbox[#1]{#3}{\color{#2}\rule{\width}{\height}}}%
\wordbox[#1]{#3}{#4}}

\definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.84,1,1}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.64,1,0.71}
\definecolor{lightred}{rgb}{1,0.7,0.71}

\begin{document}
    \begin{bytefield}{32}
        \bitheader{0,2,4,16, 31} \\
        \bitbox{2}{12} & \bitbox{2}{\textcolor{WildStrawberry}{65}} 
              & \bitbox[lrt]{28}{}\\
        \wordbox[lr]{1}{\textcolor{WildStrawberry}{65}-bit EC Public Key}\\
        \bitbox[lrb]{5}{} & \colorbitbox[lrt]{lightcyan}{27}{}\\
        \colorwordbox[lr]{lightcyan}{3}{256-bit RSA Signature} \\
        \colorbitbox[lrb]{lightcyan}{5}{} & \bitbox[lt]{27}{}\\
    \end{bytefield}

    \begin{bytefield}{32}
        \bitheader{0,2,4,16, 31} \\
        \bitbox{2}{12} & \bitbox{2}{\textcolor{WildStrawberry}{65}} 
              & \bitbox[lrt]{28}{}\\
        \wordbox[lr]{1}{\textcolor{WildStrawberry}{65}-bit EC Public Key}\\
        \bitbox[lrb]{5}{} & \colorbitbox[lrt]{lightcyan}{27}{}\\
        \colorbitbox[lt]{lightcyan}{5}{}\colorbitbox[r]{lightcyan}{27}{} \\
        \colorbitbox[lr]{lightcyan}{32}{256-bit RSA Signature} \\
        \colorbitbox[l]{lightcyan}{5}{}\colorbitbox[br]{lightcyan}{27}{} \\
        \colorbitbox[lrb]{lightcyan}{5}{} & \bitbox[lt]{27}{}\\
    \end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the option ! But it seems tht when including the options, it doesn't display the frame around anymore... Have you a workaround ?

Comment: @EisenHeim I'm not sure to understand your question. My second example is a workaround for this problem which is shown in first example. Do you have a different one?

Comment: For another application, I tried to do it with a simple example, juste a `colorbitbox` on a 2 boxes-packet. But the borders around the colored box have disappeared, unless I explicitely say I want them with `[lrbt]`. I found it odd, it's just that. I tried with this : `\begin{bytefield}{32}
\bitheader{0-31} \\
\bitbox{4}{Four} & \bitbox{8}{Eight} &
\colorbitbox{lightcyan}{16}{Sixteen} & \bitbox{4}{Four}
\end{bytefield}`

Comment: @EisenHeim. This one is easy. Change `\newcommand{\colorbitbox}[4][]{%` with `\newcommand{\colorbitbox}[4][lrtb]{%`. This way, every colorbitbox has its four sides drawn by default. And for `colorwordbox` the default could be `lr`.